# Statement class in Rails obsolete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment

I was seeing this guide for how to implement PayPal Payouts in rails and, at this code box, material from, [here](https://www.cookieshq.co.uk/posts/paypal-payouts-on-ruby-on-rails)

```
Statement.pendings.find_in_batches(batch_size: 500) do |payout_batch|
  @payout = Payout.new({
    :sender_batch_header => {
      :sender_batch_id => SecureRandom.hex(10),
      :email_subject => 'You have received a payment from CookiesHQ'
    },
    :items => payout_items(payout_batch)
  });
end
begin
 @payout_batch = @payout.create
 # Logic to update any statements
rescue ResourceNotFound => err
 logger.error @payout.error.inspect
end
```

I don't know if the Statement class is still used, and I don't find any help in the official PayPal documentation neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a `Statement` table that contains a list of recipients that need
>   paying. It also includes how much we should pay them, along with their
>   PayPal email.

`Statement` is just a model created by the author of the tutorial and has nothing to do with Rails or the PayPal SDK.